# How to check for capital letters using regular expressions in QTP?

Tags: regex, qtp, checkpoint

I need to check the login page of a website using QTP. I have a list of usernames in the global datasheet. I need QTP to pass only those usernames which are in smaller case using the standard checkpoint. I used [a-z]+ in the regular expression. But it is passing those usernames which are in uppercase also. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

negate uppercase in the whole string like this:

```
^[^A-Z]+$
```

Comment: @Nitish, I've checked marco's regex and it *does* work. Are you sure you ticked the **Regular expression** checkbox?

Comment: I've checked the Regular expression checkbox. When I use Marco's regex its not accepting uppercase. But its also rejecting lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use

^ and $ match the positions at the beginning and end of the string, which mean search the entire string for the specific patter.

[A-Z] Means a range of characters between A to Z in Uppercase; means the 1st Character of the string must be in Capital letter.

Thanks,

Rekha